# How to resolve 'Cannot GET /' error on Localhost?

Tags: node.js, express, mern

I am working on a Nodejs Express project and I keep getting 'Cannot GET /' error on Localhost. This is my server.js file

```
console.clear();

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const dbConnect = require("./config/dbConnect");
require("dotenv").config();

dbConnect();

app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api/user", require("./routes/user"));
app.use("/api/restaurant", require("./routes/restaurant"));
app.use("/api/item", require("./routes/item"));
app.use("/api/cart", require("./routes/cart"));
app.use("/api/order", require("./routes/order"));

const PORT = process.env.PORT;

app.listen(PORT, (err) =>
  err
    ? console.error(err)
    : console.log(` server is running on http://Localhost:${PORT}..`)
);
```

Can someone please tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Could You provide link to the repo ?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because you did not bind the `/` path to any request. You can simply add:

```
app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));
```

and then add an `index.js` file in your routes folder, that handles the request.

Answer (score 0):

How is your index from the file displayed?

Just put above getting you port

```
app.get('/', (req, res)=> {
    res.send("Home Page");
});
```

Now when you load your project, you will see the "Home Page" on the browser.

If you have a dedicated index route then treat as you did others.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because of there is no default route is mentioned.
To solve this you need to make one default route.Like below

```
app.use('/', require('./routes/main'));
```